# How to remove a child instance before appending a new one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am adding a component at each click of a button using the following code:

```
      var ComponentClass2 = Vue.extend(FramePicture)
      var instance2 = new ComponentClass2({
        propsData: {
          frame: this.frames
        }
      })
      instance2.$mount()
      this.$refs.frameContainer.appendChild(instance2.$el)
```

This works great, but at every click, each element appears below the previous one. As I want any new element to be displayed in the same position as the previous one, I thought to remove it at each subsequent click before adding the new one, like this:

```
      if (this.instance2.$el) {
        this.$refs.frameContainer.removeChild(this.instance2.$el)
      }
```

This gives me: 'Cannot read property '$el' of undefined' and prevents any element to be displayed.

I thought then to set a variable to 1 as soon as the first image is displayed and modify the removeChild block to:

```
      if (this.showingFrame === 1) {
        this.$refs.frameContainer.removeChild(this.instance2.$el)
        this.showingFrame = 0
      }
```

This allow to render the first element but give the same error at second click.

What I am doing wrong? how do I remove the element?

**UPDATE**

After suggestion in comment, I can now remove the instance when a certain condition is met, but I can't render the new instance2 anymore. If I console.Log(instance2.$el), i can read it, but it doesn't render.

This is what I've done:

```
        if ((this.currentBubble === 0) && (this.frames.picture)) {
        //first remove previous instance        
        this.$refs.frameContainer.remove()
        //then render new instance
        var ComponentClass2 = Vue.extend(FramePicture)
        var instance2 = new ComponentClass2({
          propsData: {
            frame: this.frames
          }
        })
        instance2.$mount() // pass nothing
        this.$refs.frameContainer.appendChild(instance2.$el)
        console.log(instance2.$el)
      }
```

so the question now is how do I render the new Instance2 after I have removed the previous one?

Comment: i find it easier to just use `this.instance2.$el.remove()` im not entirely sure where youre doing the remove part but instnace2 isnot necessarily on 'this'

Comment: @Jonathan, this works well, thanks. However once I execute `this.instance2.$el.remove()` I can't mount the new instance2. if I console.log(instance2.$el), it exist, but it doesn't render. See update in the question for code

Comment: have you checked if its exists in html ? if it does you maybe just need to set position or visiblitly correctly

Comment: oh wait youre removing the whole frameContainer

Comment: you are right, I was removing the frameContainer. However, replacing that with `instance2.$el.remove()` will error me: 'instance2' was used before it was defined. And if I define it, when the code needs to execute it, it tells me 'Cannot read property '$el' of undefined'. However it works very well if I remove instance2 straight after I have appended it, but it is not what I need.

Comment: so im asuming the variable for instance is only in thecurrent scope so I suggest etiher declaring it once outside the scoep or just remove it by this.$refs.frameContainer.children[0].remove() (this only works as long as you only have one child element in the container )

Comment: Thanks, it works for me!